# How to use Config::IniFiles module to read files

Tags: perl, config

I have been using multiple files for reading different types of configurations but I understand that I might be able to use Config::IniFiles modules and use a single file. My files structure is something like below, can someone help me in understanding how to achieve this. I have been using normal open command for different files, so another question is whether that will be directly replaced by this. Please note that I have to loop through each section

NOTE: earlier I had each [DomainCredentials] And [ProviderCredentials] in different files

```
[DomainCredentials]

DomainName=SERVER
CustomerCOde=CUSTOMER1

[ProviderCredentials]

Class=A
Routine=B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for, but:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Tiny;

my $config = Config::Tiny->new()->read("config.txt");

print $config->{'DomainCredentials'}{'DomainName'}, "\n";
```

yields:

```
SERVER
```

Comment: How do i loop through this, like I used to loop through the file when I used `open` operator.. @ysth

Comment: the module does it for you; you don't need to do anything but use the $config hash it produces.

Comment: I see from a different question that you are actually trying to ask about Config::IniFiles; I'd be happy to update my answer to use that if you still want to use that.